# r- 'regr.xgboost' does not support factor input

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

I keep getting an error that regr.xgboost does not support factor input, I am trying to use the Hyper-paramter to determine parameter values for the train model.

```
train <- createDummyFeatures(train)

test <- createDummyFeatures(test)

train_task <- makeRegrTask(data = train, target = "purchase")

xgb_learner <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost", nrounds = 10, nthread = 1, 
                           par.vals = list(objective = "reg:linear", eval_metric ="rmse"))


xgb_param_set <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("nrounds", lower = 100, upper = 500), 
                              makeIntegerParam("max_depth", lower = 1, upper = 10), 
                              makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.1, upper = 0.3),
                              makeNumericParam("lambda", lower = -1, upper = 0, trafo = function(x) 10^x))
tune_control <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10)

resample_desc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 4)
```

Everything works fine untill i run tuneParams function, dont know what I am missing. I have made factor variable into dummies using createdummyfeature

```
tuning_params <- tuneParams(learner = xgb_learner, task = train_task, 
                            resampling = resample_desc, par.set = xgb_param_set, control = tune_control)

xgb_Hyper_model <- train(setHyperPars(learner = xgb_learner, par.vals = tuning_params$x), train_task)
```

This is the output of the code:

```
xgb_learner <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost", nrounds = 10, nthread = 1, 
+                            par.vals = list(objective = "reg:linear", eval_metric ="rmse"))
> xgb_param_set <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("nrounds", lower = 100, upper = 500), 
+                               makeIntegerParam("max_depth", lower = 1, upper = 10), 
+                               makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.1, upper = 0.3),
+                               makeNumericParam("lambda", lower = -1, upper = 0, trafo = function(x) 10^x))
> tune_control <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10)
> resample_desc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 4)
> tuning_params <- tuneParams(learner = xgb_learner, task = train_task, 
+                             resampling = resample_desc, par.set = xgb_param_set, control = tune_control)
[Tune] Started tuning learner regr.xgboost for parameter set:
             Type len Def     Constr Req Tunable Trafo
nrounds   integer   -   - 100 to 500   -    TRUE     -
max_depth integer   -   -    1 to 10   -    TRUE     -
eta       numeric   -   - 0.1 to 0.3   -    TRUE     -
lambda    numeric   -   -    -1 to 0   -    TRUE     Y
With control class: TuneControlRandom
Imputation value: Inf
[Tune-x] 1: nrounds=400; max_depth=6; eta=0.125; lambda=0.221
Error in checkLearnerBeforeTrain(task, learner, weights) : 
  Task 'train' has factor inputs in 'gender, age, city_category, stay_in_current_cit...', but learner 'regr.xgboost' does not support that!
```

first 6 rows of the data:

```
 occupation marital_status product_category_1 product_category_2 product_category_3 purchase prop_aboveavg_occ prop_aboveavg_age
1         10              0                  3                 NA                 NA     8370         0.5000000         0.5000000
2         10              0                  1                  6                 14    15200         0.5333333         0.5263158
3         10              0                 12                 NA                 NA     1422         0.7500000         0.8000000
4         10              0                 12                 14                 NA     1057         0.3636364         0.5000000
5         16              0                  8                 NA                 NA     7969         0.9230769         1.0000000
6         15              0                  1                  2                 NA    15227         0.5454545         0.5543071
  prop_aboveavg_gender prop_aboveavg_city_category prop_aboveavg_marital_status prop_aboveavg_stay_in_current_city_years gender.F gender.M
1            0.5833333                   0.5468750                    0.5419847                                0.5625000        1        0
2            0.4820144                   0.4213836                    0.4244186                                0.4343434        1        0
3            0.6851852                   0.6250000                    0.6250000                                0.7647059        1        0
4            0.5000000                   0.3875000                    0.4269006                                0.3835616        1        0
5            0.7302632                   0.7681159                    0.7211538                                0.7857143        0        1
6            0.5955734                   0.5714286                    0.6250000                                0.5803571        0        1
  age.0.17 age.18.25 age.26.35 age.36.45 age.46.50 age.51.55 age.55. city_category.A city_category.B city_category.C
1        1         0         0         0         0         0       0               1               0               0
2        1         0         0         0         0         0       0               1               0               0
3        1         0         0         0         0         0       0               1               0               0
4        1         0         0         0         0         0       0               1               0               0
5        0         0         0         0         0         0       1               0               0               1
6        0         0         1         0         0         0       0               1               0               0
  stay_in_current_city_years.0 stay_in_current_city_years.1 stay_in_current_city_years.2 stay_in_current_city_years.3
1                            0                            0                            1                            0
2                            0                            0                            1                            0
3                            0                            0                            1                            0
4                            0                            0                            1                            0
5                            0                            0                            0                            0
6                            0                            0                            0                            1
  stay_in_current_city_years.4.
1                             0
2                             0
3                             0
4                             0
5                             1
6                             0
```

Comment: Can you share the input data please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I have added the first 6 rows of the data. Thanks!)

Comment: Can you please share the complete data in a way that allows to reproduce the problem? Ideally as a CSV somewhere.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can you please advise on how to share the csv file, I have not been able to find a way to do that.

Comment: An easy way to do that is to use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: I have created a dropbox link to the csv file, hope it works. thanks https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdh9ua87i8a8g1o/data.csv?dl=0

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it works for me with the full data. How did you split into train and test?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have used the same algorithm for a binary classification problem and it works fine, is it possible that all variables have to be categorical to ensure the whole dataset is numerical after one hot encoding ?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. Can you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?